# Keycloak Module load from artifact

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, keycloak, jboss-tools, redhat-sso

I added custom module to keycloak (**keycloak version 2.5.5, RH-SSO 7.1.GA**). Module_PATH/main/module.xml like that;

(Like this example http://blog.keycloak.org/2016/07/loading-providers-and-themes-from-maven.html) =>

```
<resources>
    <artifact name="com.template:my-tryer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <!-- <resource-path path="my-tryer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/> resource-path is work-->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
    <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
</dependencies>
```

Maven local repo looks a remote nexus server (central remote repo, setting.xml configured).

When i use resource-path tag in module.xml (using jar path), it works successfully.

But, when i use artifact tag in module.xml, i take this exception;

```
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to resolve artifact 'com.template:my-tryer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' (position: END_TAG seen ... @6:60) 
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseArtifact(ModuleXmlParser.java:838)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:739)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:535)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
        ... 15 more
```

What is the problem ?

Can Keycloak not look .m2 file or can not access ?

Please help,

Comment: Hello, please, try to always provide the versions of the software being used in the questions. For your case, the keycloak version number.

Comment: keycloak version number added (version 2.5.5, RH-SSO 7.1.GA).